# JQuery Ajax - Undefined index in multiple JSON data set

Tags: json, jquery

I'm returning a JSON data set via JQuery Ajax, which I then want to use to set values of text boxes.  The data set can be empty or up to 3 sets of data.  In JQuery I have:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/get_diagnosis.php",
    data: {
        case_id: caseId,
        userId: user_id
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(returnedData) {
    if(typeof returnedData[0].diagnosis !== 'undefined'){
    $('#diagnosis_l1').text(returnedData[0].diagnosis);
    }
    if(typeof returnedData[1].diagnosis !== 'undefined'){                           
$('#diagnosis_l1').text(returnedData[1].diagnosis);
}...
```

The JSON data (only one set in this example):

```
[{"diagnosis":"Roger 1"}]
```

Now, with just the one set in the JSON data, the code doesn't proceed out of the Ajax success part.  In Firebug console it shows as returnedData[1] is undefined (as expected).  However using `if(typeof returnedData[1].diagnosis !== 'undefined'){` doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: you can also check it by `if(returnedData[0].diagnosis){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`returnData` is your array of object. As there is only 1 object in this array, `returnData[1]` is undefined => you cannot access `returnedData[1].diagnosis`, it will throw exception. It should be:

```
if(typeof returnedData[1] !== 'undefined'){
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
returnedData[0] && $('#diagnosis_l1').text(returnedData[0].diagnosis);
returnedData[1] && $('#diagnosis_l1').text(returnedData[1].diagnosis);
```